# Nodejs stream API and AWS S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, node-streams

I am absolutely confused by NodeJS stream API. I am trying to build a pipeline with a couple of streams piped to each other. It looks somehow like this:

```
S3ReadStream -> ParseTransform -> PassThrough -> CustomFilter -> Serializer -> PassThrough
```

What I struggle with is error/finish handling. Generally I try to use `stream.pipeline()` rather than `readable.pipe(writable)`.

For example, when I look into the source code of S3 node.js SDK for `.upload` I see that `managed_upload.js` handles events in this manner: `error` causes cleanup, `readable` causes draining and `end` causes submit. This looks pretty intuitive to me.
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/v2.391.0/lib/s3/managed_upload.js#L185

The problem is that when I use `.pipeline` and `error` occurs for example in `ParseStream` then the error does not propagate to other streams (destroy is called without error which leads to plain `close`).

Here can be seen that `opts.error` is never set:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v10.15.3/lib/internal/streams/end-of-stream.js#L78

While here can be seen that that destroyer is always called without error
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v10.15.3/lib/internal/streams/pipeline.js#L81

What more, `.pipeline` doesnt seem to call `end` on last writable stream as can be seen in code bellow:

```js
const { PassThrough, pipeline } = require('stream')
const a = new PassThrough().on('end', console.log.bind(console, 'a'))
const b = new PassThrough().on('end', console.log.bind(console, 'b'))
const c = new PassThrough().on('end', console.log.bind(console, 'c'))
pipeline(a, b, c, () => {})
a.end()
```

It might be just me but after reading [official docs about](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_streams_callback) it doesn't correspond with the behavior I experience nor with what I see in code.

Is there a reliable and easy way how to propagate error through pipeline i.e. whenever an error occurs anywhere in the pipeline all streams get an error thus attempts to "cleanup" or "recover"? Is there maybe a library that can build "intuitive" pipelines that do not contain tons of hidden pitfalls or do I need to babysit every stream by carefully handling all its events?